# Normalize values according to category in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this

```
#    pubdate  lang Count
# 0  20140619 en   3
# 1  20150308 en   1
# 2  20140207 en   1
# 3  20180319 en   1
# 4  20150223 en   1
```

I would like to normalize the count by replacing it with itself divided by the average count/year.

For example, here is how the table looks at the end

```
#    pubdate  lang Count
# 0  20140619 en   1.5
# 1  20150308 en   1
# 2  20140207 en   0.5
# 3  20180319 en   1
# 4  20150223 en   1
```

So for year 2014, the average of all counts was (3+1)/(2 rows of 2014) = 2, then each value was divided by it.

I thought about first duplicating the frame, having a year column, then grouping per year, then changing values in first table according to that.

I do not know how to do it in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one slicing on the year substring and using it as a grouper, then divide the `Count` by the `mean` with `transform` to preserve the shape of the dataframe:

```
df['Count'] /= df.groupby(df.pubdate.astype(str).str[:4]).Count.transform('mean')
```

---

```
print(df)

    pubdate lang  Count
0  20140619   en    1.5
1  20150308   en    1.0
2  20140207   en    0.5
3  20180319   en    1.0
4  20150223   en    1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also calculate step by step keeping all temporary calculations.
First convert `pubdate` to datetime type and extract year:

```
import datetime 
df['pubdate_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pubdate, format='%Y%m%d').dt.to_period('Y')
```

then group by year and calculate mean of `Count`:

```
df['year_mean'] = df.groupby(['pubdate_year']).Count.transform('mean')
```

finally just divide columns:

```
df['normalized_count'] = df['Count'] / df['year_mean']
```

result contains all steps of calculations:

```
    pubdate lang  Count pubdate_year  year_mean  normalized_count
0  20140619   en      3         2014          2               1.5
1  20150308   en      1         2015          1               1.0
2  20140207   en      1         2014          2               0.5
3  20180319   en      1         2018          1               1.0
4  20150223   en      1         2015          1               1.0
```

If You don't need to keep temporary calculations:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['Count','pubdate_year','year_mean']).rename(columns={'normalized_count':'Count'})
```

```
    pubdate lang  Count
0  20140619   en    1.5
1  20150308   en    1.0
2  20140207   en    0.5
3  20180319   en    1.0
4  20150223   en    1.0
```